PyCUDA installation error on Windows: failed building wheel for pyproject.toml
I write in the command prompt:
python -m pip install pycuda

and I obtain the following error during PyCUDA installation on Windows 11 pro:
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.41.34120\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycuda
Failed to build pycuda
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (pycuda)

I think that it is a common problem because I have found other threads about this error, but I found only confused suggestions: I didn't find any definitive solution. The environment configuration is as follows
nvcc is installed and works fine:
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2024 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Sep_12_02:55:00_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2024
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.6, V12.6.77
Build cuda_12.6.r12.6/compiler.34841621_0

CUDA_PATH and CUDA_PATH_v12_6
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.6
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.6

Visual studio build tool free

** Visual Studio 2022 Developer PowerShell v17.11.5
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
NVIDIA Nsight Visual Studio Edition provides tools for GPGPU and graphics development.  Copyright © NVIDIA 2010 - 2024.
NVIDIA Nsight Visual Studio Edition - CUDA support provides tools for CUDA development and debugging.

Python 3.13.0 works fine
Windows version and system path:
Windows 11 Pro 23H2 build 22631.4317 
Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22700.1041.0
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.6\bin;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.6\libnvvp;
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0;
C:\Program Files\Python313\;%SystemRoot%\system32;
%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2024.3.2\;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\Hostx64\x64;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python313\Scripts;

pip list
contourpy       1.3.0
cycler          0.12.1
fonttools       4.54.1
kiwisolver      1.4.7
matplotlib      3.9.2
numpy           2.1.2
packaging       24.1
pillow          11.0.0
pip             24.3.1
pyparsing       3.2.0
python-dateutil 2.9.0.post0
setuptools      75.3.0
six             1.16.0
wheel           0.44.0

Thanks

SOLVED!
Python is too new !!! XD XD XD
I installed Python 3.11.5 and I installed pycuda without other issues.
